# Error when using gdal/ogr and python to clip a "shp" file by a "shp"

Tags: python, ogr, clip

I am new to the gdal/ogr library for python and I was wondering how to clip a shp file by another shp file. I think I am having trouble with the syntax. Thanks - Stefan

I keep getting a windows error message: "WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

```
import subprocess

##The features used to clip the input features.**

clipping_shp = "US_States_STATE_NAME__Oregon.shp"

##The feature class to be created.**

output_shp = "output1.shp"  

##The features to be clipped.**

input_shp = "broadcast_national_ALL.shp"

##Clipping process**

subprocess.call(["ogr2ogr", "-f", "ESRI Shapefile", "-clipsrc", clipping_shp, output_shp, input_shp])
```

Comment: Hi Stefan, Welcome to GIS.se :) Thanks for adding the specific error message. It reveals that your problem is likely not about GIS exactly, but basic python and operating system interaction and thus better suited for StackOverflow.com. That said, using subprocess like this is ill-advised. You'd be better to use the python module directly, [one example](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33370/is-there-a-way-to-get-at-cs-ogrlayer-intersection-or-ogrlayer-clip-in-pytho) or at least test if the files exist, `if exist input_shp: {...do stuff..}; else: print 'cant find %s!' % input_shp`

Comment: how would i go about running the module directly'

Comment: I am having trouble finding any documentation or examples of ogr's clip method

Comment: computer spits out --> ‘ogr2ogr’ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to call ogr2ogr.
It is also possible to use OGR directly in Python but this is a little bit more difficult.

Here the solution if you call ogr2ogr as a subprocess:

```
import subprocess

# The features used to clip the input features.
clipping_shp = "US_States_STATE_NAME__Oregon.shp"
# The feature class to be created.
output_shp = "output1.shp"  
# The features to be clipped.
input_shp = "broadcast_national_ALL.shp"

# Clipping process
subprocess.call(["ogr2ogr", "-f", "ESRI Shapefile", "-clipsrc", clipping_shp, output_shp, input_shp], shell=True)
```

Comment: i tried this and got "WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: Here is the error :

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Stefan\Desktop\CLIPPING\clip_shp_to_shp.py", line 26, in <module>
    clip_shp_to_shp(directory, shpclip)
  File "C:\Users\Stefan\Desktop\CLIPPING\clip_shp_to_shp.py",

Comment: line 20, in clip_shp_to_shp
    subprocess.call(["ogr2ogr", "-f", "ESRI Shapefile", "-clipsrc", shpclip, os.path.basename(source) + "_clip.shp", source])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 524, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: I simplified the code a little bit. Can you please give it a second try. You have to save the code either in the directory where your shapefiles are or paste the path into the code.

Comment: do I have to make the out put shp file ahead of time or will it do it for me? Sorry I am used to arcpy.

Comment: I am getting the same error as well

Comment: It will create it for you. You just have to enter a name in the code (like here `"output1.shp"`).

Comment: Can you post the error again. It should be different than the previous one.

Comment: thats what I thought. I continue to get that "windows cannot find file" error

Comment: Did you save the Python file in the same folder as your shapefiles?

Comment: clipping_shp = "C:\\Users\\Stefan\\Desktop\\CLIPPING\\US_States_STATE_NAME__Oregon.shp"
output_shp = "output1.shp"
input_shp = "C:\\Users\\Stefan\\Desktop\\CLIPPING\\broadcast_national_ALL.shp"

# Clipping process
subprocess.call(["ogr2ogr", "-f", "ESRI Shapefile", "-clipsrc", clipping_shp, output_shp, input_shp])

Comment: yes and I just wrote the path directly in there

Comment: I edited the code again with your shapefile names. If you use exactly the code above and save it into your `CLIPPING` folder it should work. If not than I don't know either.

Comment: I'm thinking its an issue with the subprocess.call itself. What version of python do you have?

Comment: What does it do it you add `shell=True` to the subprocess.call (see edited code)?

Comment: OOOOooo No error message...but no saved file

Comment: Sorry than i don't know.

Comment: oh Don't apologize. You helped me get pretty far! Thanks man!

Comment: I figured it out! the code works great it was just a user error lol. Thanks!

Comment: @stefan - I am having the same issue, what exactly was your user error? pls see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71915/clip-and-copy-files-to-same-directory-structure-using-ogr-gdal-with-python