# clipping ESRI shapefiles along with shx and dbf

Tags: shapefile, ogr2ogr

I've seen [other answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62584) detailing how one can clip a `.shp` file with `ogr2ogr` but this just returns a clipped set of geographic features.  I also want to clip the `.shx` and the `.dbf` in the same manner.  Is this possible?

For instance, if I have `all-of-rhode-island{.shp, .shx, .dbf}` in my current directory, I could try:

`ogr2ogr -clipsrc 41.31 -71.87 41.50 -71.53 smaller-ri all-of-rhode-island`

But `ogr2ogr` can't figure out which driver to use with that input file.

My actual goal is to take a TIGER Census file and reduce its size drastically.  I only need a few features, but I do need "matching" `.dbf` and `.shx` files.

Comment: Are you looking for a specific solution? You mention OGR so I guess you are not using ArcGIS/MapInfo as what you are asking would be trivial in those GIS systems. If you are looking for an open source solution then consider [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/)?

Comment: I would love something for Linux or the command line or (best of all) python.  I will try QGIS Desktop, thanks.  I had been stumped looking at QGIS /Browser/, not realizing there was a difference.

Comment: The shapefile format spans the three files; it is **required** that the .shx and .dbf have the same number of records as the .shp (or it's not a valid shapefile).

Answer (score 1):

`ogr2ogr` *is* the tool to use for this, I've realized.  It will clip `.shp`, `.shx`, `.dbf` and other files if you run it correctly (which I was not doing).

I was using latitude as x and longitude as y, but that is incorrect.  This was what I eventually used:

`ogr2ogr -clipsrc -71.87 41.31 -71.53 41.50 smaller-ri.shp rhode-island.shp`

Comment: Note: ogr2ogr does have shapefile as a default output format but some other GDAL tools have other defaults, like GML. Your command is correct but myself I give always output format explicitly even for shapefiles by addin `-f "ESRI Shapefile"`. It makes me feel that I am the one who controlls the situation.